# Spring-test unexpectedly fails, how best triangulate the error?

Tags: java, spring-3, spring-test

This basic Spring test of a Spring 3 controller gives me a response code 404 result instead of the expected 200:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class RootControllerMvcTest extends AbstractContextControllerTests {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac)
.alwaysExpect(status().isOk()).build();
}

@Test
public void viewIndex() throws Exception {
this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(view()
.name(containsString("index"))).andDo(print());
}
```

AbstractContextControllerTests:

```
@WebAppConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml")
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
public class AbstractContextControllerTests {

@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac; }
```

I have verified the controller method itself with another test, but when I use the context the test fails even as the controller does serve the proper page when run in container.

The controller in question looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class RootController {
@Autowired
CategoryService categoryService;    

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String index(Model uiModel) {    
            uiModel.addAttribute("categories", categoryService.findAll());
        return "index";
    }
```

Clearly I'm not testing what I think. Any suggestion how to triangulate this issue?

I posted the full web mvc file at [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/4umhbY0t) to not clutter all space up here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: The `value` attribute for `@WebAppConfiguration` is **not** an XML configuration file but rather the **root** directory of your web application. So your current test configuration could never work.

Assuming that `applicationContext.xml` and `webmvc-config.xml` are the XML configuration files for your *root* and `DispatcherServlet` `WebApplicationContext`s, respectively, try redefining `AbstractContextControllerTests` as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextHierarchy ({
  @ContextConfiguration("/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"),
  @ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml")
})
public abstract class AbstractContextControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    protected WebApplicationContext wac;

}
```

By the way, *abstract* test classes must actually be declared as `abstract`. ;)

Regards,

Sam (author of the Spring TestContext Framework)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Sam. I had to add paranthesis too (edited the code above), but this solved my issue, thank you! I should have questioned not making a´class with "Abstract" in the name, well, abstract, but I borrowed the basic structure from [Spring-MVC-Showcase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc/AbstractContextControllerTests.java) and must have assumed this was the proper way of doing it. Thanks for pointing out that newbie error too.

Comment: Glad it worked for you! And thanks for pointing out the missing parentheses. I just typed in that code without an IDE. ;) I've fixed the example now.